# Scoring Metric for scikit-learn's LassoCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I'm using scikit-learn's [LassoCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) function. During cross-validation, what [scoring metric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) is being used by default?

I would like cross-validation to be based on "Mean squared error regression loss". Can one use this metric with LassoCV? One can specify a scoring metric for [LogisticRegressionCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html), so it may be possible with LassoCV too?

Comment: Not possible in current implementation. You can put this as an issue to scikit-learn github page and see what the response is.

Comment: Do you know what the current scoring metric is?

Comment: R2 is the default metric for most regression estimators. See the description of [score() for LassoCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.score)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`LassoCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) uses R^2 as the scoring metric. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#specifying-an-objective-metric):

> By default, parameter search uses the score function of the estimator
>   to evaluate a parameter setting. These are the
>   sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score for classification and
>   **sklearn.metrics.r2_score for regression**.

To use an alternative scoring metric, such as mean squared error, you need to use [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or [`RandomizedSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) (instead of [`LassoCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html)) and specify the `scoring` parameter as `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'`. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#specifying-an-objective-metric):

> An alternative scoring function can be specified via the scoring
>   parameter to **GridSearchCV**, **RandomizedSearchCV** and many of the
>   specialized cross-validation tools described below.

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer is wrong, as it quotes the documentation of Grid Search, but `LassoCV` uses regularisation paths, not grid search.
In fact in the docs page for `LassoCV`, it says that the loss function is:

```
(1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1
```

Meaning that its minimising the MSE (plus the LASSO term).

Comment: I don't think it's wrong. I think you two are answering different questions, with the accepted answer answering the OP's question, and you answering a different question. The OP asked for the "scoring metric" DURING CROSS VALIDATION. That's not equivalent to asking what objective function is solved, which is what you're answering, I think?